# Laravel unique rule validator breaking during Validator::make

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to check to see if (a) column(s) is/are unique by using the `Rule::unique('table')->where(function($query) use($x) {...});` functionality but when I pass this into my validator I am getting a strange error. What I think is happening is that it is trying to check if a value is equal in the where the statement that I provided but also a column that it THINKS is the unique ID column for the table but it is not so it is breaking.

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $uid = 660000000;
    $rule = Rule::unique('member_record')->where(function ($query) use ($uid) {
        return $query->where('uniqueID', $uid);
    });

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'fullName' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2'],
        'member_id' => [
            'bail', 'required', 'Numeric', $rule,
            'exists:new_benefits_member,member_id'
        ],
        'email' => ['bail', 'required', 'email', 'confirmed', 'unique:user,email'],
        'password' => [
            'required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed',
            'regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/'
        ],
        'terms' => ['required']
    ]);
}
```

However, then I am getting an error that looks like the following.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'member_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `member_record` where `member_id` = 660000000 and (`uniqueID` = 660000000))

What my only assumption is that when I am passing data into the `Validator::make($data...` it is trying to compare the $rule with the $data array and it is messing it up. Let me know if you have any fixes that I can try out.

Comment: Looks like the wrong table name: `member_record`. The table should be `new_benefits_member` which has the column `member_id`

Comment: @adam I am trying to access two different tables. I am trying to see if the value is unique in the member_record table in the uniqueID column and if that same number exists as a member_id in the new_benefits_member_table.

Comment: Right. The `member_id` column doesn't exist in the `member_record` table.

Comment: @adam no it does not, so you're suggesting by having the exists rule right after it, it is also affecting the previous rule? is there a better way to format this if so?

Comment: No, I'm saying the generated query from your rule is causing the issue.

Comment: @adam Yes, I know but I can not figure out how to format the query correctly to exclude the "member_id = 660000000 and" portion of the query I have played with it quite a bit and have not found the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205972/discussion-between-a-dady-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Rule::unique() function can take 2 parameters as shown below

```
public static function unique($table, $column = 'NULL')
{
    return new Rules\Unique($table, $column);
}
```

if column is left as 'NULL' then this will default to the name of the key in the validator::make($x, [] <--- array

as shown in this example.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $uid = 660000000;
    $rule = Rule::unique('member_record')->where(function ($query) use ($uid) {
        return $query->where('uniqueID', $uid)->orwhere('client_member_id', $uid);
    });
    $data['foo'] = 0;
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'foo' => [$rule]
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

results in this response

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `member_record` where `foo` = 0 and (`uniqueID` = 660000000 or `client_member_id` = 660000000))

If you would like to exclude "is equal to" in the first part of the where clause you would perform a unique check like this

```
'member_id' => ['unique:member_record,foo']
```

If you would like to add additional where clauses then you would want to do something like this

```
'member_id' => ['unique:member_record,foo,NULL,id,bar,' . $uid]
```

This will return SQL looking like this

> select count(*) as aggregate from `member_record` where `foo` = 660000000 and `bar` = 660000000